# Not getting desired output from PHP class

Tags: php, class, categories, class-method

This is my very first question actually. I am under a learning process of OOP PHP and trying to design my first class for Category. Here is my code

```
<?php
class category{

public  $catid;
public $datacol;

    public function __construct($catid=0)
    {
        $this->catid=0;
        $this->datacol=$this->load($catid);         
    }

    public function load($catid)
    {
        global $conn;
        $sql=' select * '
            .' FROM tbl_categories'
            .' WHERE catid='.$catid;
        if (!($res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) || !mysqli_num_rows($res)>0) 
            return false;
        $this->datacol = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
        $this->catid = $this->datacol['catid'];
        return true;
    }

    public function reload() {
        return $this->load($this->getId());
    }

    /* ------------------> Getter methods <--------------------- */
    public function getId() { return $this->catid; }
    public function getName() { return $this->datacol['category']; }
    public function getOneliner() { return $this->datacol['categoryoneliner']; }
    public function getBrief() { return $this->datacol['categorybrief']; }
    public function getThumb() { return $this->datacol['timg']; }
    public function getImage() { return $this->datacol['limg']; }
    public function getParentID() { return $this->datacol['parentcat']; }
    public function getPagetitle() { return  $this->datacol['catpagetitle']; }
    public function getKeywords() { return $this->datacol['catkeywords']; }
    public function getMetadesc() { return $this->datacol['categorymetadesc']; }
    public function getPriority() { return $this->datacol['priority']; }
    public function getRemarks() { return ($this->datacol['remarks']); }
    public function getRow() { return $this->datacol; }

}

?>
```

Now,
When i create its object from other file with a code as below:

```
$cat=new category(10);
echo var_dump($cat);
echo var_dump($cat->getId());
echo var_dump($cat->getName());
```

The output gives me the correct catid when called getID(). But Shows NULL for getName() or any other function other than getID().

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `print_r($this->datacol)` and see what fields do you have there

Comment: Remove `return true;` in load function

Comment: Still shows NULL

Comment: @u_mulder 
    echo $cat->datacol; // shows nothing... and var_dump of the same shows NULL

Comment: In your `constructor` you are setting `datacol` with the result of your `load` function but in the same function you are setting the value of `datacol` already.

Comment: Should `$this->catid=0;` be `$this->catid=$catid`; in your constructor?

Comment: ok... i think there is nothing being loaded in datacol .... as i print the following
    echo var_dump($cat->datacol);
It shows the output as below:
bool(true) .... So how do i get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Arnold Gandarillas said, you are overwriting `$datacol` in the constructor.

Your constructor calls `load()`, which sets `$datacol`:

```
public function load($catid)
{
    ...
    $this->datacol = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    return true;
}
```

The function then returns `true`. In the constructor, this `true` is assigned to `$datacol`, overwriting the previous value:

```
public function __construct($catid=0)
{
    $this->catid=0;
    $this->datacol=$this->load($catid);         
}
```

Change the constructor to something like this:

```
public function __construct($catid=0)
{
    if ($catid > 0)
        $this->load($catid);         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright - look closely to your function:

```
public function load($catid)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql=' select * '
        .' FROM tbl_categories'
        .' WHERE catid='.$catid;
    if (!($res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) || !mysqli_num_rows($res)>0) 
        return false;
    $this->datacol = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    $this->catid = $this->datacol['catid'];
    return true;
}
```

So, you function returns either `true` of `false`. And this boolean values is assgined to `$this->datacol` here:

```
$this->datacol = $this->load($catid);
```

As this assignment happens **after** you did `$this->datacol = mysqli_fetch_array($res);`, your `$this->datacol` becomes either **true** or **false**, and holds no real data from mysql.

So, **one** of the solutions can be to remove assignment:

```
public function __construct($catid=0)
{
    $this->catid=0;
    $this->load($catid);         
}
```

In this case your `$this->datacol` is not overwritten.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Worked :) Getting my first ever php class to work

Answer (score 0):

its simple  $this->datacol =  $this->load($catid); is not required

you have assigning $this->datacol twice

```
 public function __construct($catid=0)
    {
        $this->catid=0;
        $this->load($catid);         
    }
public function load($catid)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql=' select * '
        .' FROM tbl_categories'
        .' WHERE catid='.$catid;
    if (!($res=mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) || !mysqli_num_rows($res)>0) 
        return false;
    $this->datacol = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
    $this->catid = $this->datacol['catid'];
    return true;
}
```

please add if anything is missing